# How to run pg_ctlcluster with CentOS?

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, postgresql-9.6

I'm using CentOS 7 with EPEL Repo and installed Postgresql 9.6 which is a need for a webshop application. Now some propel installation script wants to execute `pg_ctlcluster`. The Installation ends with an error:

```
Exception: sudo: pg_ctlcluster: command not found
```

I checked `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin`, there is only `pg_ctl`, but no `pg_ctlcluster`. Some said `pg_ctl` and `pg_ctlcluster` are not exactly the same. It looks like `pg_ctlcluster` is a Ubuntu thing. It's used for Postgres Cluster (...).

Do you have any ideas what's the best way to replace `pg_ctlcluster`?

Just copy/symlink pg_ctlcluster -> pg_ctl sounds not like it should be. Maybe someone have a suiteable RPM.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this one?

Comment: @GoonNguyen I never checked. I tried to install Spryker Webshop Software which requires Postgres. I opened an incident there: discuss.spryker.com/t/centos-installation-no-vm-failed-no-pg-ctlcluster-available/331

Answer (score 0):

`pg_ctlcluster` is not part of core PostgreSQL, but the PGDG Debian install packages come with an additional utility command of that name.

So that propel installation script is written for Debian or Ubuntu Linux.

You'd best ask the provider of the script for a script that supports the Redhat-based Linux distrubutions.

Comment: I contacted the vendor. Some expert confirmed the bug and they want to fix it soon.

Comment: Great. That's always better than a questionable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt want to overwork the whole PHP installation script, so this fix worked for me:

```
- $process = $this->getProcess(sprintf('sudo pg_ctlcluster %s main restart --force', $postgresVersion));
+ $process = $this->getProcess(sprintf('sudo -i -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_ctl %s restart', NULL));
+ $process = $this->getProcess(sprintf('exit', NULL));
```

**Not for use in productional enviroments**